# Docker-compose directory bind does not work as intended

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I am trying to insert an entrypoint script via volume bind.

My compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

    database:
        container_name: database
        image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
        ports:
            - "1435:1433"
        volumes:
            - ./db/init:/usr/src/app
        command: sh -c 'ls -lah /usr/src/app/; chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh; ./usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh & /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr;'
        environment:
            ACCEPT_EULA: Y
            SA_PASSWORD: <password>
```

The two files I want to insert are in the specified init folder and seem to be added to the container since the output of a `docker-compose up` starts like this:

```
Creating network "docker_evaluation_deploy_default" with the default driver
Creating database ... done
Attaching to database
database    | ls: cannot access '/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh': No such file or directory
database    | ls: cannot access '/usr/src/app/initdb.sql': No such file or directory
database    | total 4.0K
database    | drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Mar  4 09:43 .
database    | drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Mar  4 11:58 ..
database    | -????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? entrypoint.sh
database    | -????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? initdb.sql
database    | chmod: changing permissions of '/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh': No such file or directory
database    | sh: 1: /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh: not found
database    | 2020-03-04 11:58:37.03 Server      Setup step is copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\master.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf'.
...
```

The files are added but are not accessible.

I am using a Windows10 Host with docker version 2.2.03 (42716) on stable channel installed. The docker-ompose version is 1.25.4.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you're on a Windows 10 host then shouldn't `./db/init:/usr/src/app` be more Windows-like?

Comment: Sure, but it does not make any difference. I'm planing to use this file on both linux and windows, thats why it was currently written that way. What I tried look like this: `.\db\init:/usr/src/app`

Comment: Well, I was thinking more like `/c/some_path_to_your_folders/db/init:/usr/src/app`.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but it produces the exact same result. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, because docker seem to mount the folder (note that the expected files are there (entrypoint.sh and initdb.sql) but cannot be used or specified as files).